# I am very confused about this question can someone please help me solve it. Thanks!

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, equivalence-relations, binary

Lucy works in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ of vectors $x = [x_1, . . . , x_n]^T$ . Chris chosen a different basis and handles vectors $x’  = [x’_1 , . . . , x’_n ]^T$ , where $x$ and $x’$ are related by $x = Px’$ . Lucy is studying the linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^n $ associated with the $n\times n$ real matrix $A$, i.e. $x \mapsto  y = Ax$. How shall we find the coordinates y’ of the transformed vector when we know the coordinates $x’$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, use a descriptive titles. "I am very confused about this question can someone please help me solve it. Thanks!" says nothing about the subject of the title. But more importantly, show your work on the problem. If you don't show some effort, your question will be poorly received in this site.

Answer (score 0):

$y’=Py$ and $x’=Px$. Moreover $y=Ax$ so that

$y’=Py=PAx=PAP^{-1}x’$

Thus $y’=PAP^{-1}x’$